# Having Trouble with SMP (Strobe Media Playback)

Tags: javascript

I'm having some difficulties getting paths within SMP to work right.  In the demo files, it includes an HTML file that works great when I just double click it.  But when I move it elsewhere, say one directory up, it fails even when I update the paths.  I kept all the rest of the files in a folder called 'strobe'.  Even when I put scrobe/ in front of paths, it still doesn't work.  I cut out some of the HTML to cut down on the size of this post.  Thank you in advance.

```
<head>
    <title>Strobe Media Playback</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/swfobject.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/ParsedQueryString.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        // Collect query parameters in an object that we can
        // forward to SWFObject:

        var pqs = new ParsedQueryString();
        var parameterNames = pqs.params(false);
        var parameters = {
            src: "http://mediapm.edgesuite.net/strobe/content/test/AFaerysTale_sylviaApostol_640_500_short.flv",
            autoPlay: "false",
            verbose: true,
            controlBarAutoHide: "false",
            controlBarPosition: "bottom",
            poster: "images/poster.png"
        };

        for (var i = 0; i < parameterNames.length; i++) {
            var parameterName = parameterNames[i];
            parameters[parameterName] = pqs.param(parameterName) ||
            parameters[parameterName];
        }

        // Embed the player SWF:

        swfobject.embedSWF
        (
        "StrobeMediaPlayback.swf", 
        "StrobeMediaPlayback", 
        640, 
        480, 
        "10.1.0", 
        "expressInstall.swf", 
        parameters, 
        {
            allowFullScreen: "true"
        }, 
        {
            name: "StrobeMediaPlayback"
        });

        /* Uncomment this code to be notified of playback errors in JavaScript:

         function onMediaPlaybackError(playerId, code, message, detail)            
         {
            alert(playerId + "\n\n" + code + "\n" + message + "\n" + detail);            
         }

         */

    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
    <!-- .Verdana {
        font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    }
    -->
    </style>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't exactly figure out what I was doing wrong, but if anyone else runs into this problem, I found that there's a [setup.html](http://www.osmf.org/dev/1.5gm/setup.html) in the source code that will get one up and running for your own needs.